# PostSharp Unable to use OnMethodInvocationAspect

Tags: c#, postsharp

I am using Post sharp **Runtime Version - v2.0.50727**  **Version - 4.2.20.0**, I am not able to able to use `OnMethodInvocationAspect`. What am I doing wrong here?

> Csharp Runtime Version - v4.0.30319

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnMethodInvocationAspect` is no longer available in PostSharp. You can use `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` or `MethodInterceptionAspect` instead.

Here is the list of available aspect classes: http://doc.postsharp.net/simple-aspects

And here is an example of `MethodIntercetionAspect`: http://doc.postsharp.net/example-guithread

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PieroAlberto This is my answer :)